# Facebook unattended nodejs app for posting videos/photos to page

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-access-token

I'd like to make an unnattended nodejs app that will post a video/photo from a list to a Facebook page everytime it is executed (from command line).

I can do that using an access token generated with the Graph API Explorer, but this kind of token expires in a short period of time, so it is not useful for me. This method would be useful if the token is never expiring, but I cannot find a method to get a never expiring token (at least with API version v3.0).

Is there anyone that knows how to do this? Is it possible to get a "never expiring token" with permissions to post to my page with v3.0 API version?

Thank you!

Comment: did you read the docs? they specifically mention extended page tokens, they never expire.

Comment: Yes, I've read the docs, but for me it looks like docs are not up to date because I cannot get a page token that never expires that's working properly. Every web I look for an explanation on how to do this explains the same procedure, but this procedure cannot be followed nowadays using Facebook developer tools.

Comment: The process works fine, even with API version 3.0 - I just tested it, and got a page access token without any default expiry, as expected.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/ it´s a bit older, but the procedure should still be the same.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers. Finally I could generate the "never expiring page token", but I really don't understant why I couldn't before. I've had to delete all my Facebook apps and create a new one. After that I've been able to generate the token as explained everywhere, so I don't really know what I was doing wrong. Anyway, thank you very much for your help. Best regards!